# fixed quantity on product variable

Tags: php, variables, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to accomplish one thing on WooCommerce, but I can find almost zero information about it. It is like the following scenario:

I sell buttons and have 1000 in stock. I would like the customer to choose between buying 10, 30, 100 and 500 buttons in a drop-down list. The price for each button is lower when you buy 500 compared to 10, 40 etc.

This works just the way I want by using product attributes and product variations. BUT the stock is not effected the way I want since the system thinks that it is one package of 100 buttons and therefore reduces the stock by 1.

I've found [this](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-variable-stock-management/screenshots/) plugin, but it doesn't work, it never updates my settings

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't code, just look at plugins. Woocommerce has a very rich plugin ecosystem. Some examples:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-bulk-discount/screenshots/

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing/

This in particular looks close:

https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing-discounts/7119279

[image]

Comment: I've already saw many plugin, but noone fit my request.i need something like this: " https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-variable-stock-management "